# Remove option from select [AngularJS]

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to remove selected option after ajax success...

This is my seleceted object: `vm.group.name`

and I try  to delete it like this:

`vm.group.name.remove();`

but no success, any idea how can solve it?

Comment: what does the `remove()` function look like?

Comment: set vm.group.name = null;